# Make desktop default downlaod location?

Tags: mac, firefox, download, desktop

Is it possible to redirect a Mac download to go to the deksktop instead of the downloads folder?

I use Firefox

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools >  Options > General Tab > Save files to... and browse to desktop folder.